# Android libpng ERROR: Failure processing PNG image - maven-plugin

Tags: android, maven, m2e, aapt

Compiling my project with android-maven-plugin gave me the following png error.  Eclipse with android-m2e compiles and deploys without a problem onto my tablet.  Is this an issue with the aapt command and libpng?

```
[INFO] /Users/foo/android-sdk-macosx/platform-tools/aapt [package, -f, -M, 
/Users/foo/source/app/abc-android/AndroidManifest.xml, -S, /Users/foo/source/app/abc-
android/res, -S, /Users/foo/source/app/abc-
android/target/unpack/apklibs/com.abc.aws.android_aws_apklib_1.0/res, --auto-add-overlay, 
-A, /Users/foo/source/app/abc-android/target/generated-sources/combined-assets/assets, -I, 
/Users/foo/android-sdk-macosx/platforms/android-15/android.jar, -F, 
/Users/foo/source/app/abc-android/target/abc-android-0.1-SNAPSHOT.ap_, --debug-mode]
[INFO] libpng error: Not a PNG file
[INFO] ERROR: Failure processing PNG image /Users/foo/source/app/abc-android/res/drawable-hdpi/login_full_screen.png
[INFO] /Users/foo/source/app/abc-android/res/layout/achievement_grid_item.xml:7: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'src' with value '@drawable/achievement_3_in_arow').
[INFO] /Users/foo/source/app/abc-android/res/layout/achievement_grid_item_post_class.xml:6: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'src' with value '@drawable/achievement_3_in_arow').
[INFO] /Users/foo/source/app/abc-android/res/layout/ant_fragment.xml:8: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'background' with value '@drawable/distance_bg').
[INFO] /Users/foo/source/app/abc-android/res/layout/ant_fragment.xml:89: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'background' with value '@drawable/cadence_bg').
[INFO] /Users/foo/source/app/abc-android/res/layout/ant_fragment.xml:168: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'src' with value '@drawable/heat_arrow_narrow_full_both').
[INFO] /Users/foo/source/app/abc-android/res/layout/ant_fragment.xml:198: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'src' with value '@drawable/avg_max_separator').
[INFO] /Users/foo/source/app/abc-android/res/layout/ant_fragment.xml:231: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'background' with value '@drawable/power_bg').
[INFO] /Users/foo/source/app/abc-android/res/layout/ant_fragment.xml:318: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'src' with value '@drawable/total_effort_bg').
[INFO] /Users/foo/source/app/abc-android/res/layout/ant_fragment.xml:350: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'src' with value '@drawable/heat_arrow_wide_full_both').
[INFO] /Users/foo/source/app/abc-android/res/layout/ant_fragment.xml:380: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'src' with value '@drawable/avg_max_separator').
[INFO] /Users/foo/source/app/abc-android/res/layout/ant_fragment.xml:415: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'background' with value '@drawable/resistance_bg').
```

Answer (score 0):

Open the png file in MS Paint and re save it as png file. It will convert the png to 32-bit format. Since Android supports both 24-bit and 32-bit png's , it makes me think there is something with **Adobe Photoshop** generated png's which Android does not like.

Refer : [Canvas & Drawables](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/2d-graphics.html)